# Firebase no connection detected?

Tags: swift, firebase

I have been using Firebase and was curious to see if they have a function that can tell me if the user has or does not have an internet connection so that I can disable any features in my application? Anybody know? I am trying to do this in Swift 2!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you done any research on Firebases documentation? A quick Google search yielded this result. Read this and i'm sure you will answer your own question.

https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/offline-capabilities.html